# How does nginx limits inheritance on error_page work

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am trying to set up rate limits on error page location in nginx, but once I define global limits,  it stops working.

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
worker_processes 4;
pid /opt/nginx-iag/pid/nginx_iag.pid;
timer_resolution 100ms;

error_log /opt/nginx-iag/logs/error-uko.log debug;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    map_hash_bucket_size 1024;

    limit_req_zone 1 zone=global:1m rate=30r/s;
    limit_req_zone 1 zone=error_page:1m rate=20r/s;

    server {
        listen 9080;

        #limit_req zone=global burst=30 nodelay;

        location /abcdef {
            limit_req zone=error_page burst=20 nodelay;

            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:12345;
        }

        error_page 404 = /abcdef;
    }
}
```

When I use this configuration, rate limit on error_page is 20r/s. But once I uncomment server level limit_req directive, the limit become 30r/s.
According to nginx documentation, 30r/s limit can be inherited only if there are no limits defined. Why does server level limit overwrite nested one, and what is the right way to define rate limits for error_page?